# Analogue for simple modules in vector space setting

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, modules

A non-zero module is simple/irreducible if it has no non-trivial proper submodules. Suppose $M$ is a simple module over the ring $R$. If $R$ is a field, is there a special name for $M$? ie simple /irreducible vector space? Is there anything special about such a vector space?

Comment: Yes, such vector space are special. They don't have a proper subspace. So ...what are the vector spaces without a proper non-zero subspace?

Comment: hi turnip_man; simple vector spaces are precisely the vector spaces of dimension 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no special name other than simply "1-dimensional $R$-vector space".

Comment: @L.G. Sorry friend: not a possibility.